# How can I calculate the number of samples required to reach given confidence level?

Tags: estimation, parameter-estimation, confidence-interval

You found some rotten fruit in your farm's harvest of 200,000 apples. How many apples do you need to sample to estimate the number of rotten apples ±20%, 95% confidence?

All sampled fruit needs to be thrown out, so it's important to find the least amount of apples required to reach 95% confidence that the estimate is within ±20% of the actual amount of rotten apples.

---

You get to sell all remaining (untested) apples to a applesauce cannery. The cannery has the machinery to break and test each individual apple, so they'll eventually know the exact amount of rotten apples.

But your contract demands that if you are outside 20% of your estimate, factory doesn't have to pay for the apples. Your boss says he's alright with 95% confidence in our estimate.

How many apples do you test/destroy/sample in order to determine your estimate, maximizing your chance to be paid for the remaining untested apples?

---

If data is helpful, here's what happened last year in each of your orchards. You need to tell the factory how many rotten apples you estimate this year from the same orchard. Unfortunately it's only your second year and the previous farmer burned his logs. ;)

```
            Last Year       Last Year           This Year       This Year
orchard_id  rotten_apples   total_apples        total_apples    est_rotten_apples
A           4543            60913               63959           ?
B           6213            57862               60755           ?
C           196606          665926              699222          ?
D           13858           263879              277073          ?
E           12785           141849              148941          ?
F           7441            153486              161160          ?
G           6362            228504              239929          ?
H           3738            57030               59882           ?
I           193528          2394342             2514059         ?
J           73251           867756              911144          ?
K           45118           224893              236138          ?
L           27216           291949              306546          ?
M           63013           768708              807143          ?
N           1240            20982               22031           ?
O           11856           121023              127074          ?
P           5185            30041               31543           ?
Q           5496            26408               27728           ?
R           558             11339               11906           ?
S           8118            145720              153006          ?
T           10568           104308              109523          ?
U           7313            43311               45477           ?
V           14163           169633              178115          ?
W           1897            16339               17156           ?
X           ?               ?                   200000          ?
```

Each apple is free to test, but the factory will pay you `$0.10` per apple (even rotten ones), so long as your estimate is within ±20% (per orchard). If you didn't have to sample any apples, that's `$720,951` this year (from the above 23 orchards). How can I maximize your farm's revenue this year?

---

Extra credit: You just acquired `Orchard X`. This year it harvested 200,000 apples. Given what's happened in the other orchards, how many should you sample from this new orchard to reach 95% confidence that your estimate will fall within ±20%?

Comment: You need information on the distribution.  If, say,  there is either $0$ or $1$ rotten apple with $\frac 12$ probability then you'll need to sample all $200,000$.

Comment: Then you are out of luck.  You need information regarding the distribution, as my example illustrates.

Comment: In a practical situation, you should know the distribution of rotten apples.  Presumably it is vaguely normal, and you have the historical mean and standard deviation.  It should not happen in a real world situation that you have absolutely no idea of what the underlying distribution is.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not interested in metaphors.  Either this is a practical situation in which case we have real world data to draw from, or it is an abstract problem and the necessary assumptions should be provided.  I don't think you have a well posed question here.

Comment: Sorry, I don't think anything I have to say will be of use.  Good luck.

Comment: @lulu : Why do you believe this problem is *not* parameter estimation of a binomial distribution applicable only to this population of $200\,000$ apples?

Comment: I am writing an answer that will hopefully make sense to you. Both you and @lulu have valid arguments.

Comment: @EricTowers  It's possible that this is what it is, though with that assumption I'd advise just using the normal approximation.  The difficulty is that we don't know what the probability of an individual success is (same as knowing mean and $\sigma$ for the normal), but yes you can try to estimate that as you go.   Had the OP specified that this was the model to be assumed, that would be a valid approach.  But normality is a strong assumption, often violated in practice.  It's dangerous to assume that every unspecified situation is normal!

Comment: @lulu, I added data from last year for each orchard. Does this help?

Comment: Ok!  That is very helpful.  It illustrates the point I was making.  You have orchards, like $G$, with less than $3\%$ bad apples.  You also have orchards like $C$ with nearly $30\%$.  It would be dangerous to use a single historical number to describe both of these.  But you shouldn't have to...presumably you know which orchards your actual sample comes from, and presumably you know if these percents can be regarded as stable from year to year.  If these numbers are decently stable, then I think you can use the data to work up a solid model.  Are they decently stable?

Comment: Yes, year to year, expected to be stable. But we only have one year of data, so it's hard to quantify.

Comment: I just added `Orchard X` the data above. It shouldn't come as a surprise to find out that it harvested 200,000 apples. How many should you sample from this new orchard to maximize your farm's revenue?

Comment: @lulu : This is not an *assumed* model.  The total population (in all the universe) is $200\,000$ apples.  Each apple is binarily classified as "good" or "rotten".  The OP asks to estimate the PDF of cannery observed probability rotten given the size and probability rotten of a sample.  This is **literally** parameter estimation of a binomial.  There is no assumption.  Further, if you choose to use data from prior apple populations, then you fail to describe this population.

Comment: @EricTowers, can you help put some meat on the bones of that for me? It sounds like you get the challenge, can you point me in the right direction to calculating the answers?

Comment: @EricTowers  As I say, the issue is whether Normal is a good assumption or not.  As it stands, I'd would not be surprised if this distribution is multi-modal.  But, fine.  I expect I am over thinking it.  It seems clear that the OP wants to assume a roughly normal model, so I concede the point.

Comment: @lulu It might be multimodal when viewed with respect to each orchard, but not the case when you treat the sample as one giant orchard.

Comment: I was directed to Stan Brown's https://brownmath.com/stat/sampsiz.htm for direction. I'm reading through it myself, but thought I'd share here if it helps any others come up with a solution.

Comment: I also found Survey Monkey's Sample Size Calculator (https://www.surveymonkey.com/mp/sample-size-calculator/) and tried plugging in the OP data: Population Size 200k, Confidence Level: 95, Margin of error: 20%. Result: 25. If this is true, and I were to estimate population based on 25 examples, I would expect to be within 20% of actual 95% of the time. Do I understand that correctly?

Answer (score 1):

I am going to ignore some of the higher-level underlying math that is at play here. I'm assuming that this is the type of response you are interested in.

You are trying to calculate confidence intervals for a sample with unknown mean and unknown standard deviation. This means that you will somehow have to derive these from the data. Assuming the true underlying distribution is normal (this is kind of an okay assumption in general, but again, requires a lot of math that you would not be interested in seeing).

The standard deviation $\sigma$ is replaced by the "estimated standard deviation" $\bar{\sigma}$, also known as the $\bf{standard \ error}$. Standard error is an estimate for the true value of the standard deviation, $\bf{the \ distribution \ of \ the \ sample \ mean \  \bar{x}}$   is no longer normal with mean $\mu$ and standard deviation $\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}$. Instead, the sample mean follows the t-distribution with mean $\mu$ and standard deviation $\frac{\bar{\sigma}}{\sqrt{n}}$ . The t-distribution is also described by its degrees of freedom. For a sample of size $n$, the t distribution will have n-1 degrees of freedom. The notation for a t distribution with $k$ degrees of freedom is $t(k)$. As the sample size n increases, the t-distribution becomes closer to the normal distribution, since the standard error approaches the true standard deviation  for large $n$.

Now, for a population with unknown mean $\mu$ and unknown standard deviation, a confidence interval for the population mean, based on a simple random sample of size $n$ is

$\bar{x} \pm t^{*}\cdot \frac{\bar{\sigma}}{\sqrt{n}}$

Where $t^{*}$ is the upper $(1-C)/2$ critical value for the t-distribution with $n-1$ degrees of freedom, $t(n-1)$.

In your case, you need to find $n$ such that $t^{*}\cdot \frac{\bar{\sigma}}{\sqrt{n}}$ is less than or equal to 20.

Since we do not know the value of $\frac{\bar{\sigma}}{\sqrt{n}}$ it may seem that this is impossible, however, we can easily bound $\bar{\sigma}$ by 1, which reduces the problem to finding $t^{*}/{\sqrt{n}}\leq 0.20$. the right value of $n$ for this turns out to be 99. That is,after upper bounding the standard deviation by 1, the minimum number of apples you need to sample to estimate the proportion of rotten apples (assuming rotten apple takes value 1 and non-rotten takes value 0 when eestimating mean and s.d.) is 99. Hope this approach helps.

EDIT: The standard deviation is actually bounded above by 1/2, so sampling 99 appples actually puts you within $\pm 10 $%

In order to estimate the proportion of rotten apples over your entire farm (assuming one giant orchard) you can use [roulette wheel select](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fitness_proportionate_selection) to first decide the sub-orchard [A,B,...,W] to choose a random apple from, and then decide which apple to choose (choosing the random apple within the sub-orchard might be tricky, but you could always take a slightly larger sample if need-be). I would reccomend choosing a number between 1 and the number of trees in the sub-orchard randomly and then picking an apple from that tree (how you order them is not important, and you don't actually need to count just be close). Obviously this isn't going to be completely 100% random, but try to make it "as random as possible." Repeat this process 99 times and calculate the average number of rotten apples. this will be within 10% of true average with 95% confidence.

Comment: This is very helpful. Can you help me glue any of the concepts above to the data examples?

Comment: Sure. Lets say you have a collection of 10 apples, and you individually check to see if each is rotten. take the number of rotten apples and divide by 10 and that is your estimated mean (it's the same as saying that we assign a rotten apple value 1 and a non-rotten apple value 0 and whatnot).  This calculation says that if you sample 99 apples at random from your entire orchard, that is, if you took the apples from all of the different sites, threw them into a gigantic bin, and then sampled randomly from that bin,

Comment: the number of rotten apples you saw, divided by 99 would be within  AT MOST $\pm$ 20% of the true proportion of rotten apples over your whole orchard with 95% confidence. The true mean may actually lie within a more narrow range depending on the true standard deviation, but you know it's no worse than $\pm 20%$

Comment: If you wish to develop a model for actually acquiring this sample, I would reccomend a "roulette wheel" type model. The way to think of it is as follows: you have a pie chart with one slice for each orchard and the size of a slice corresponding to a given orchard is proportional to the percentage of apples that orchard contributes to the overall number of apples. You then spin this wheel 99 times, recording the orchard you landed on. This is a flexible model which lets you test subsets of orchards very easily. If you would like  details feel free to message me.

Comment: Alright, so I sample my 24 orchards collectively, 100 times, noting the orchard and count of good and rotten, by orchard. How many apples should I sample each time? How did you know to do it 100 times? Should the roulette wheel orchard selection be representative of population of apples (i.e. an orchard with 10 trees should be 1/10 as likely to be sampled as the orchard with 100 trees)? Last, I looked up how to message on stack exchange... turns out lack of private message is a feature.

Comment: No problem. I actually noticed that you can get a slightly better bound on the number of apples you need to sample for your desired confidence range (it has to do with the fact that standard deviation is actually bounded above by 1/2 assuming binomial estimation)... I will edit my answer and provide you with the details on estimating the sample.

Comment: I tried to take your roulette wheel advice @mm8511 and ran it 10 times using the above orchard data. Here are the results: https://pastebin.com/raw/D9fVDXF1 . Each Sample Set includes 100 total apples, which you can see data by orchard, and in total. `rotten_apples` ranges from `8-14` in total. Given this data, how would you use this to calculate the estimates for the above (OP) data table? For example, `Orchard A` has `63,959` total apples this year. How many do we estimate are rotten? How many samples will it take to determine my estimate within `±20%` (±12k apples)?